# Non-consistent results between ffprobe and ffmpeg for keyframes identification

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, ffprobe

Trying to identify both thumbnails and timestamps of keyframes on a set of videos, I'm getting different results from `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe`.

Taking a 1 min. long video as an example:

```sh
youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/mp4' 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHlAlN3z4ss' --output "test.mp4"
```

1/ I extract thumbnails and write on the image the timestamp at which it was extracted:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -q:v 2 -vf select="eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)","drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/Arial.ttf:fontsize=45:fontcolor=yellow:box=1:boxcolor=black:x=(W-tw)/2:y=H-th-10:text='Time\: %{pts\:hms}'" -vsync 0 thumbs/preview%05d.jpg
```

2/ I extract and save the timestamps of all keyframes:

```
ffprobe -v error -skip_frame nokey -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time -select_streams v -of csv=p=0 test.mp4 | sort -n > keyframes_timestamps.txt
```

3/ Comparing results, I figure `ffprobe` found 29 keyframes, while `ffmpeg` found only 32. Comparing manually, we can see that specific keyframes are not detected by ``ffprobe` while most are very similar.

```
ffprobe_ts  ffmpeg_ts
0.000000    00:00:00.00
5.366667    00:00:05.367
7.200000    00:00:07.200
8.666667    00:00:08.667
10.100000   00:00:10.100
11.500000   00:00:11.500
14.233333   00:00:14.233
15.333333   00:00:15.333
17.366667   00:00:17.367
NO_TS       00:00:18.833
20.800000   00:00:20.800
24.533333   00:00:24.533
25.700000   00:00:25.700
26.033333   00:00:26.033
```

On larger videos, this happens for around less that 5% of the keyframes.

I can't find an explanation about that, does anyone have a clue ? or an advice on where/what I should inquire further ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all I-frames are keyframes. `-skip_frame nokey` will skip non-KF I-frames.

Comment: Oh thanks, it worked ! So, using this ffmpeg command I got the same results as with ffprobe : `ffmpeg -skip_frame 'nokey' -i test.mp4 -q:v 2 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/Arial.ttf:fontsize=45:fontcolor=yellow:box=1:boxcolor=black:x=(W-tw)/2:y=H-th-10:text='Time\: %{pts\:hms}'" -vsync 0 thumbs/preview%05d.jpg`.